# How Jmeter response for a invalid login credential

Tags: jmeter

I have given an incorrect credentials in for my login request using the GET function. But Jmeter shows that sampler as passed. Wondering on how this could happen.

Even after adding the Post processor - Stop Test option the sampler keeps on executing the complete thread count. Kindly help sorting out this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Response Assertion for this and put a String that identifies the login process as successful.

As long as application returns a valid Response Code (200) JMeter cannot guess that this response says "Invalid Credentials", you have to tell it that if page contains for example "Invalid Credentials" then it means response is in error.

JMeter considers a page as failed (if not assertion is set) only if the HTTP Response code if different from 2XX , 3XX.